# Node-RED: Can you read from local storage in a function node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, local-storage, node-red

I have stored some data in local storage using Javascript.

When i navigate to a new page, i can display the data in a HTML template node and that works fine.

Is there a way to set the msg.payload to include the data from local storage, so that i can use it in an SQLite query.

I have tried to use the html node to get the contents of what local storage returned but unfortunately, that did not work.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the term "local storage" to mean a file on the server, or the Application LocalStorage area of the browser (on the client)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No

Browser local storage is not available to a Node-RED function as it is all running on the server side, not the browser.

The only thing you could do is use a HTTP in/response pair to server a HTML/javascript page to the browser, read the storage and then use websockets/http post to inject the data back into the flow.

Comment: Thanks, managed to use ajax and JSON node to get the data from browsers localStorage into the msg.payload